# How to instantiate a class declared in module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, nodemailer

I'm following this [tutorial](https://codemoto.io/coding/nodejs/nodemailer-email-templates-using-node) to send a templated mail with nodemailer and email-template

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var emailTemplates = require('email-templates');
var sendMailTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

module.exports = {
  _template: null, 
  _transport: null,

  init: function (config) {
    var d = Q.defer();

    emailTemplates(config.emailTplsDir, function (err, template) {
      if (err) {
        return d.reject(err);
      }

      this._template = template;
      this._transport = nodemailer.createTransport({ service: 'Sendgrid', auth: { user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME, pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD } });
      return d.resolve();
    }.bind(this));

    return d.promise;
  },

  send: function (from, to, subject, text, html) {
    var d = Q.defer();
    var params = {
      from: from, 
      to: to,
      subject: subject,
      text: text
    };

    if (html) {
      params.html = html;
    }

    this._transport.sendMail(params, function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return d.reject(err);
      } else {
        return d.resolve(res);
      }
    });

    return d.promise;
  },

  sendMail: function (from, to, subject, tplName, locals) {
    var d = Q.defer();
    var self = this;
    this.init({ emailTplsDir: "email-templates" }).then(function () {
      this._template(tplName, locals, function (err, html, text) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return d.reject(err);
        }

        self.send(from, to, subject, text, html)
          .then(function (res) {
            return d.resolve(res);
          });
      });
    }.bind(this));

    return d.promise;
  }
};
```

I didn't understand how to instantiate a the class declared like that ! I always get the error

```
    var mailer = require('../../utils/mailSender');

var locals = { name: "New User", siteName: "Takwinland" };
                        mailer.sendMail('contact@takwinland.com', "dhaker.odesk@gmail.com", 'Welcome!', 'signup', locals).then(function () {
                          res.status(200).send('A welcome email has been sent to ' + "dhaker.odesk@gmail.com" + '.');
                        }, function (err) {
                          if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                        });
```

> TypeError: Class constructor Email cannot be invoked without new

is there a problem in the tutorial or just me being dumb !

Comment: How and where are you instantiating it?

Comment: var mailer = require('../../utils/mailSender');
then I call var locals = { name: "New User", siteName: "Takwinland" };
                        mailer.sendMail('contact@takwinland.com', "dhaker.odesk@gmail.com", 'Welcome!', 'signup', locals).then(function () {
                          res.status(200).send('A welcome email has been sent to ' + "dhaker.odesk@gmail.com" + '.');
                        }, function (err) {
                          if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                        });

Comment: I will update the post so you can better understund

Comment: Call the class with a `new`

Comment: how to do it exactly ?

Comment: Take a look at the file and line number reported in the error... because I can not see anywhere where you are calling `Email()`.

Comment: I don't have Email(), it may be a plugin function (nodemailer or email templates) that's mostly code I have..

Comment: @MedDhakerAbdeljawed Well then it's either a bug in those libraries or you're calling them wrong (and it's still a bug because of the unhelpful error message). Find out where the `Email` constructor is used and report the issue.